# Override first argument when calling a program

Tags: bash, shell

I need to override the first argument when I call a binary.

Since it's the program name I have two solutions:

- move the binary and call it with its new name; or
- create an alias (if the shell allows it).

However, sometimes I need to completly remove the first parameter.

I wrote a simple program in C that does the job:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return execve(argv[1], NULL, NULL);
}
```

I there a built-in way to do it with the shell? A solution for bash would be prefered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override it with `exec -a`, though you can't make it unset.

For example, to run `busybox` with `argv[0]` set to `ls`:

```
( exec -a ls busybox )
```